# In Jmeter how to call a method with parameters

Tags: http, groovy, jmeter, jenkins-groovy

AT Jmeter, I have one thread group which consists of two HTTP request, One of the HTTP request contains JSR223 Listener which has a method calculateSum, can that method be called from another JSR223 Listener from another HTTP request sampler

Need to call method by passing parameters and returns the result of it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of [JMeter 5.6.2](https://lists.apache.org/thread/49dnwvyozy535ogwqvdvbkwkgk0xkrrl) the only way of doing it is creating a [class](https://groovy-lang.org/objectorientation.html#_classes) with your method, compiling it and putting it into [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath)

Once done you will be able to call your method from any JSR223 Test Element after adding the necessary [import](https://groovy-lang.org/structure.html#_imports) statement

More information:

- [How to Reuse Your JMeter Code With JAR Files and Save Time](https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-reuse-your-jmeter-code-with-jar-files-and-s)
- [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)

---

There is [groovy.utilities](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#groovy) property where you can define code snippets which can later on be used in [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy), it might also be a viable alternative

Comment: 1. You should modify *user.properties* file, not jmeter.properties. 2. The correct property name is `plugin_dependency_paths`. 3. If you're loading a 3rd-pary .jar file which is outside JMeter's "lib" folder you should use `user.classpath` property. More information: [Configuring JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter) and [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-properties-customization)

Comment: Once restarted the Jmeter after given the path in the plugin_dependency_paths. The imported class is accessible as instructed in this link https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath

Comment: Is there any difference if i use jmeter.property instead of user.property file thanks in advance!